# ¿Cómo hacer que el encabezado en un documento pdf generado con R markdown ocupe todo el ancho de la página?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

¿existe alguna forma de que el encabezado ocupe todo el ancho de la página, sin respetar los márgenes del resto del documento? Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

````
---
title: ""
author: ""
date: ''

geometry: left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,twoside

header-includes:
  - "\\usepackage[spanish]{babel}"
  - "\\usepackage{fancyhdr}"
  - "\\usepackage{graphicx}"
  - "\\pagestyle{fancy}"
  - "\\fancyhf{}"
  - "\\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{"
  - "\\fancyhf{}"
  - "\\fancyhead[C]{\\includegraphics[width=15cm]{I:/markdown pdf/encabezado2.png}}"
  - "}"
  - "\\renewcommand{\\headrulewidth}{0pt}"
  - "\\setlength{\\headheight}{68.0658pt}"
  - "\\addtolength{\\topmargin}{-58.0658pt}"
  - "\\setlength{\\headsep}{0.5cm}"
  - "\\fancyfoot[C]{\\includegraphics[width=15cm]{I:/markdown pdf/pie de pagina.png}}"
  - "\\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\\thepage}"
  - "\\pagenumbering{gobble}"
  - "\\setcounter{page}{1}"
  - "\\usepackage[labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}"

output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
  html_document:
    highlight: tango
    theme: cerulean
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
mainfont: Calibri
papersize: a4
always_allow_html: true
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: "1.5"

---

\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\renewcommand\tablename{\textbf Tabla}

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
``
## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
````

Intenté cambiar "includegraphics[width=15cm]" por "includegraphics[width=pagewidth]", pero eso no funcionó.
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

De partida, ya que tienes muchas lineas que incluir a tu preámbulo, te recomiendo que cambies a :

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
```

Ese archivo preamble.tex, contendrá las líneas que incluyes aquí. En referencia a tu consulta, debes utilizar `\paperwidth` para que el tamaño sea equivalente al tamaño de tu página, y señalar el offset de la cabecera (o pie) de página. Algo como:

```
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhfoffset[L]{72.5pt}
  \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{I:/markdown pdf/encabezado2.png}}}
```